# Fourier Transform of Mixed Partial Derivative

Tags: definite-integrals, partial-derivative, fourier-transform, image-processing

My task at hand is to compute the Fourier transform of a mixed partial derivative given by:

$$\mathscr F\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} \right)(u,v)= \iint _{\Bbb R^2} e^{-i2\pi (ux+vy)}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y)  dxdy$$

Now, I have been advised that I simply need to use integration by parts to solve this. However, my trouble comes in identifying the specific variables I need to isolate and apply with the integration by parts formula. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f$, together with $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ vanish at infinity. Then we integrate by parts with respect to $x$ first and the $y$ then. We obtain

$$\mathscr F \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \right)(u,v) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-2\pi i(ux+vy)} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}dx dy $$

$$ =- \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (-2\pi i u) e^{-2\pi i (ux+vy)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dx dy = + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (-2\pi i u)(-2\pi i v) e^{-2\pi i (ux+vy)}f(x,y) dx dy $$

$$= - 4 \pi^2 uv  \mathscr F(f)(u,v).$$

Comment: I see that you just calculated the derivatives on the inside and did not apply integration by parts. Do you think it is not necessary?

Comment: You are welcome! But my second and third equalities are precisely integrations by parts.

Comment: Hmm. I guess I am having trouble seeing it because I am used to the form: $\int udv = uv - \int v du$. Is it just because one of the terms evaluates to 0?

Comment: I am using

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g'(x)h(x)dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(x)h'(x) dx + \lim_{x\to+\infty}(h(x)g(x))- \lim_{x\to-\infty}(h(x)g(x).$$

That is why we had to assume $f$, $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/ \partial y$ vanish as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: Ok. I am going to have to stare at this for a bit. I'm going to accept your answer. It seems very well done and correct.